# Passing a variable to kivy label on init

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Working on a project whose components need to be kept modular. I have a Kivy label (`StatusLabel`) in a different file that needs a variable (`alarm`) and I would prefer to pass it to the constructor, `def __init__(self, alarm, **kwargs):` I can't figure out how to do that while building the rest of the canvas.

How can I pass Jarvus's `self.alarm` to the *gui.py* file's `StatusLabel`?

Here's the workaround in its current, non-functional state. In `gui.py` I try a double import (`jarvus.py` imports `gui`) to access the attribute. This is not my intended solution.

**Main file: jarvus.py**

```
import comms
import alarm
import gui
from kivy.app import App, Builder


class Jarvus(App):
    comms_system = comms.Comms()
    alarm = alarm.Alarm(comms_system)

    def build(self):
        # comms thread
        self.comms_system.setDaemon(True)
        self.comms_system.start()
        self.comms_system.log("comms started")
        # alarm thread
        self.alarm.setDaemon(True)
        self.alarm.start()
        self.comms_system.log("alarm started")

        # this WOULD work if I only wanted the single widget
        # return gui.StatusLabel(self.alarm)

        # How can I get self.alarm into this Builder?
        return Builder.load_string(gui.KV)

 Jarvus().run()
```

And the GUI element, **gui.py**

```
KV = '''
<ScreenManagement>:
    HomeScreen:
        BoxLayout:

<HomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:

<StatusLabel>:

'''

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.transition = SlideTransition()

# HERE'S THE PROBLEM
class StatusLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, alarm, **kwargs):
        # kivy stuff
        super(StatusLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # make the button update
        self.font_size = 24
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .1)
        # self.alarm = alarm
        self.id = 'status'

    def update(self, *args):
        try:
            from jarvus import Jarvus
            self.text = Jarvus.alarm.now()
        except Exception:
            return


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'home'
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.add_widget(StatusLabel())
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I pass Jarvus's `self.alarm` to the _gui.py_ file's `StatusLabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass it to `StatusLabel` because a StatusLabel isn't even created at the moment you are calling `Builder.load_string`.

You are defining a template that's gonna be used for all `StatusLabel` from now on.

If you wanted to pass a default value that can be parsed by the kivy parser then you could've adjusted `gui.KV` to include a pattern that you can replace before calling `Builder.load_string`, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks, I think I follow. But to solve the problem, how do I implement a pattern in `gui.KV` that I can replace? So far, I've given `StatusLabel:` the property `text: app.get_alarm().now()` and that does show the time but  it doesn't update. The refresh comes from `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .1)` called by the `StatusLabel` and that is in Python, `guy.PY` and from there I cannot access `Jarvus.py` because of double importing.

Comment: Is there a way I can declare a variable in the `gui.KV` file that I can access in `gui.PY`?

Comment: In kv files you are defining templates. Variables are declared in py files. Kivy parsers files could assign values to your variables based on the template from the kivy file.

Comment: So how do I get a variable to the `gui.py` file from `jarvus.py` without `import jarvus` inside `gui.py`. Video: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbnZoI6qGS

Comment: Short answer: you can't. What you can do is use another py file. Import it in both jarvus.py and gui.py. Set the value for the alarm for jarvus and read it from gui. But this has nothing to do with kivy, or python for that matter, but with designing your application :)